# How can I mark message as read in instagrapi?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, instagram-api

I am fetching messages in direct as below:

```
messages = client.direct_threads(amount=10)

for message in messages:
    text = message.messages[0].text
    user_id = message.messages[0].user_id
    username = client.user_info(user_id).username
```

This way I can get the content of the message and the senders username. However, I can not mark the message as read.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.direct_send_seen(message.id)
```

Passing message id to direct_send_seen will mark the thread as read.